# What's the point of using octokit/core.js in a browser if storing access tokens in it is not secure?

Tags: javascript, github, github-api, octokit-js

The documentation of [octokit/core.js](https://github.com/octokit/core.js) shows examples of using the module in the browser but doesn't show how the token was acquired or where it is stored. So, I assume the token is readily available in the browser.

If storing tokens in the browser is not secure then is there any use case where accessing GitHub API using a browser is valid?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to get the token from octokit. I followed the Github Web app flow - https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#web-application-flow

What I did was store token in browser as a httpOnly cookie, then pass to my nodejs server to call Github APIs

Comment: The problem with storing the token in a httpOnly cookie is that they can be accessed by extensions installed in the browser. I don't know how to prevent that. If you do, please add that to the answer as well.

Comment: Oh I didnt know that, thats a very hacky way of getting a cookie though xD
Maybe storing the cookie in a DB along with start time of storing it would do?

Comment: Are you talking about indexeddb? If yes, then extensions can access that too. I see no way to securely store a secret in a browser.

Comment: This might help https://dev.to/cotter/localstorage-vs-cookies-all-you-need-to-know-about-storing-jwt-tokens-securely-in-the-front-end-15id